# Recognizing which distribution a coin belongs to

Tags: probability, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

I’m working in a problem that can be simplified as follows: let’s say that I have two unfair coins, one which probability of heads is 85% and another which the probabilities are unknown. The goal is to identify which is which, but we can only flip one of those two coins for a fixed number of trials. In other words, we pick one, we flip for like 10 trials and then we must decide.

We can draw the number of heads and tails for the 85% unfair coin as:
[image]

Next, we get the following table

```
|------------------|------------|--------------|
|      #heads      |  #tails    |   prob       |
|------------------|------------|--------------|
|           10     |       0    |  0.196874404 | 
|           9      |       1    |  0.347425419 | 
|           8      |       2    |  0.275896657 | 
|           7      |       3    |  0.129833721 | 
|           6      |       4    |  0.040095708 | 
|           5      |       5    |  0.008490856 | 
|           4      |       6    |  0.001248655 | 
|           3      |       7    |  0.000125915 | 
|           2      |       8    |  8.3326E-06  | 
|           1      |       9    |  3.26769E-07 | 
|           0      |       10   |  5.7665E-09  | 
|------------------|------------|--------------|
```

For the 85% headed coin, we have a large probability of having at least one tail p(#tails>1)~.8 and in particular we expected to have 1 or 2 tails in our 10 trails.
To address the actual question, my idea was to compute the likelihood that our trials correspond to the 85% headed coin. In other words

[image]

Let’s now consider three different scenarios:

1 – We have seen 6 tails out of our 10 trials

[image]

2 – We have seen 2 tails out of our 10 trials

[image]

3 – We have seen 0 tails out of our 10 trials

[image]

I would say that in scenario 1, we are pretty confident that the coin we’ve picked is not the 85% headed one. And scenario 3, we would be rather confident that it is. It is bizarre for me that the likelihood is larger for scenario 3 than scenario 2. We haven’t seen any tails at all (again we have 80% chance of seeing 1 tail or more with the 85% headed coin). It could happen that the unknown coin had 95% chance or greater of giving heads.

Something is wrong, but I can’t really figure what. I would expect that if we had 1 or 2 tails in our 10 trials the likelihood of having picked the 85% headed coin would be larger than having no tails at all.

Could someone explain please, what I am missing?

Comment: (1) You forgot to include the binomial coefficients in your likelihoods. (2) Consider studying the likelihood *ratios.*  For that purpose, you won't need the binomial coefficients, because they cancel.

Comment: @whuber, you mean this likelihood ratios: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test? People typically working in this kind of problem they frequently assume knowing the distribution of the unknown coin or at least that it is within a range. In my case, I don't have such this luxury...

Comment: No, I mean use the likelihood ratio.  It's a useful tool, especially in this case.